# Group by results which are in the same order

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a problem with grouping my resultset.

I need to group my results on `Tab_1_colName` and the (different part) the order of the results of `Tab_2_Order` if they have the same `Tab_2_Ids`.

So i have a first resultset, which looks like this:

```
  Tab_1_colName Tab_2_colName   Tab_2_Id    Tab_2_Order
    Name_1          Type_1          16          10
    Name_1          Type_2          17          20
    Name_1          Type_3          18          30
    Name_2          Type_1          16          10
    Name_2          Type_2          17          20
    Name_2          Type_3          18          30
    Name_3          Type_1          16          400
    Name_3          Type_2          17          500
    Name_3          Type_3          18          600
    Name_4          Type_1          16          10
    Name_4          Type_3          18          20
    Name_4          Type_2          17          30
```

The result which i need looks like this:

```
Group1 => (Name_1 - Name_3) with the IDs in this order (16, 17, 18),
Group2 => (Name_4) with the IDs in this order (16, 18, 17)
```

I have no Idee how to achive this. I tried to group it directly on the DB, but there i stuck on

```
SELECT 
    Tab_1_colName, Tab_2_Id
FROM 
    Tab_1,
    Tab_2
WHERE
    Tab_1_othderID = Tab_2_othderID
group by 
    Tab_2_Id, Tab_1_colName
```

My second idea was to try it with linq, but there i stuck even fast as with the pure sql try

```
dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().OrderBy(x => x["Tab_2_Order"]).GroupBy(r => r["Tab_2_Id"])
```

Any ideas how to solve my problem?

**EDIT:**

Expected Result:

First Row: Name_1 with the Tab_2_Ids order by tab_2_order.

Second Row: Name_4 with the Tab_2_Ids order by tab_2_order.

(Name_2 and Name_3 should be in the same group like Name_1 because they have the same Tab_2_Ids in the same order)

Comment: "i have a Table which looks like this:"  . . . Why does the query reference two tables?

Comment: Yeah sorry, i have a first resultset, which looks like this, on which i want to group by.

Comment: can you clarify the output you are looking for, it's not 100% clear.

Comment: I edited my question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my Problem. With the great help of another user, who unfortunately deleted his anwser before i get it to run. :(

A big thank you to you! :)

Anyway here is my solution:

```
var dtRows = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>();

var rows = dtRows.GroupBy(r =>
            String.Join(",", dtRows.Where(q => q[0] == r[0]).OrderBy(o => o[3]).Select(s => s[0]).ToArray()),
            x => x[2],
            (key, g) => new Tuple<string, string[]>(key, g.Where(s => s != null).Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray().Distinct().ToArray())
          ).ToList();

List<Tuple<string, string[], List<string>>> rowsToWrite = new List<Tuple<string, string[], List<string>>>();

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    if (!rowsToWrite.Any(x => x.Item2.SequenceEqual(row.Item2)))
        rowsToWrite.Add(Tuple.Create(row.Item1, row.Item2, new List<string>()));
    else
        rowsToWrite.Select(x => x).Where(x => x.Item2.SequenceEqual(row.Item2)).First().Item3.Add(row.Item1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don use aggregation function so you don't need grou by ..
instead use disticnt for select distinct value  and/or order by for ordering the result  eg:

```
 SELECT distinct 
  Tab_1_colName, Tab_2_Id
FROM 
  Tab_1,
  Tab_2
WHERE
Tab_1_othderID = Tab_2_othderID
order by 
   Tab_2_Id, Tab_1_colName
```